# How to cast parent class Sprite to subclass MySprite in Cocos2d-JS

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-js

I have a class MySprite as subclass of Sprite with some addition method.

```
var MySprite = cc.Sprite.extend({

    ctor:function(){
        this._super();

    },

   doSomethingStrange:function(){
   //meow meow
   }

}
);
```

In the play scene, I would like to get sprite from rootNode and cast it into MySprite so I can call doSomethingStrange from MySprite. However, I haven't found any way to cast type in javascript.

```
var PlayLayer = cc.Layer.extend(new function() {


        this.ctor=function () {
            this._super();
            var rootNode = ccs.csLoader.createNode(res.scene_playscene_json);
            this.addChild(rootNode);    
        };  

        this.meow_meow = function(rootNode){
             cat  = rootNode.getChildByTag(numberTagBegin);
             // do something here to cast cat from Sprite to MySprite
             cat.doSomethingStrange();
        };
});
var playScene = cc.Scene.extend({
    onEnter:function(){
        this._super();
        var layer = new PlayLayer();
        this.addChild(layer);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way to do it:
In your MySprite:

```
 var MySprite = cc.Sprite.extend({

    ctor:function(){
        this._super();

    }
}); /*end of extend function call*/

MySprite.prototype.doSomethingStrange = function(){
   //meow meow
}
```

And then you can access doSomethingStrange without any casting whatsoever

```
   this.meow_meow = function(rootNode){
         cat  = rootNode.getChildByTag(numberTagBegin);
         // do something here to cast cat from Sprite to MySprite
         cat.doSomethingStrange();
    };
```

The way you've declared `doSomethingStrange` in your previous example - actually is a JavaScript way of declaring a private method ([You can read more about Module pattern here](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html) in case you're curious)

There are plenty of info on JavaScript flavors of inheritance. [This article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)
may be helpful

Comment: I dont see how you cast. I think that I understood he wants to cast cc.Sprite to MySprite. So the getChildByTag return a sprite and call doSomethingStrange from there.

Comment: The purpose of "casting" is to be able to execute doSomethingStrange method of MySprite, correct?

Comment: The purpose I think is you have a cc.Sprite casted to MySprite to execute doSomethingStrange. But the start point is a cc.Sprite

Comment: Guess what, you can execute doSomethingStrange without casting, because JavaScript is not strictly typed. It will just work